# Save Image as PNG in a Portable Class Library

Tags: c#, .net, image, graphics, portable-class-library

I'm currently in the process of porting an existing C# project from the .Net Framework 4.5 to Portable Class Library [profile 111](http://embed.plnkr.co/03ck2dCtnJogBKHJ9EjY/preview). I need to save and load image data to / from a stream using the PNG format.

As you probably know, the `System.Drawing` namespace is not available in this profile, so there is no way I can use the `Bitmap` class for this, as I did previously. So far, my web research did not yield any "obvious solutions" for image compression in C# when `System.Drawing` is unavailable.

In answering this question, please assume that providing different platform-versions of my library with a mere PCL "frontend" is not an option in this case.

How to approach this?

Comment: When Googling I found a pure C# PNG library, *pngcs*, [here](https://code.google.com/p/pngcs/). It is not a PCL right now, but it does not seem to have any dependency against Windows Forms or WPF, so it should not be altogether difficult to turn it into a PCL. Worth a try? **UPDATE** Project has recently been transferred to [Github](https://github.com/leonbloy/pngcs).

Comment: I just had to check, and **yes**, the project is easily ported to PCL profile 111, it only takes a little work to circumvent a few unsupported method calls.

Comment: @AndersGustafsson That library might actually be an option - thanks! :)

Comment: I have published my PCL profile 111 port of *pngcs* [here](https://github.com/anders9ustafsson/pngcs). Completely untested yet, but it builds! Open solution *pngcs.portable.sln* and try it out. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: @AndersGustafsson I've looked into pngcs and did a performance comparison for loading PNGs between the library and System.Drawing.Bitmap. Unfortunately, that library is 5x slower, which makes it almost unusable in my case :/ The culprit appears to be the .Net DeflateStream, which consumes about 70% if the loading time. So.. still looking for alternatives. (But thanks for your help, in any case!)

Answer (score 1):

The Portable Class Library does not support any image or UI elements by design, so your problem will likely be quite difficult to solve without extracting some functionality into a minimal platform-dependent library. From doing some searching online, it seems like other devs presented with your same problem have resorted to offloading the image work to either a web service or a platform-dependent library.

Of course you could always just deal with `byte[]` and roll your own PNG encoder/decoder. Yay. Be aware there are various flavors available based on different "filters", etc.

The PCL link [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/gg597391%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) states that the assemblies available within a Portable Class Library project are:

```
mscorlib.dll
System.dll
System.Core.dll
System.Xml.dll
System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll
System.Net.dll
System.Runtime.Serialization.dll
System.ServiceModel.dll
System.Xml.Serialization.dll
System.Windows.dll (from Silverlight)
```

That last assembly is the only one I am aware of that has any image-related functionality. It contains the `System.Windows.Controls.Image` class which supports the display of an image in the JPEG or PNG file formats. The caveat, of course, (based on the matrix contained in the aforementioned link), is that this `System.Windows.dll` Silverlight assembly is only available in PCL when targeting the Silverlight platform and/or the Windows Phone 7 platform. It will not be available to the more general .NET Framework 4 platform, nor the Xbox 360 platform.

If you did end up being forced to go with a minimal platform-dependent library, the WPF framework does have the `System.Windows.Media.Imaging` namespace with comprehensive image format encoding/decoding support (including PNG format).